# Pushing data from SharePoint "New list item" to php

Tags: php, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, wss, wss-3.0

I have a list with my employers project task list. When a user adds a new project to the list, I want to push some of the data the user entered into an external site (which is run by our parent company) to store in a separate project management system.

So my question is:
Is there som way to post data (some or all fields) to a PHP-script on an external server?

I don't have any programming experience with SharePoint (or .NET in general), so if this is something that can be done with Workflows I would be very happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware there's no mechanism in SharePoint that would allow you to make a request to an external site when a list is updated.

Depending on how quickly the data added in to SharePoint needs to make its way in to the project management system, a polling solution may be your best bet.

Just create a PHP script that will pull the list from SharePoint and check for any changes (pushing them to your Project Management System is found), then setup a CRON job to run the script at given interval's (Hourly/daily etc depending on how quickly you need the changes to take effect)

Anyways, hope that helped somewhat :)

Answer (score 0):

Look into List event handlers, you can attach event handlers on list item updates/adds etc.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brianwilson/archive/2007/03/05/part-1-event-handlers-everything-you-need-to-know-about-microsoft-office-sharepoint-portal-server-moss-event-handlers.aspx

you will need a way to communicate with the php system (web service or database insert/update via c#/vb.net code.